# How to enable touch and swipe in opencart 3.0.3.2

Tags: php, css, opencart, opencart-3

I have a website [www.whitedotsports.com](http://www.whitedotsports.com) and it's on opencart 3.0.3.2. How can I enable touch and swipe product images on the product page? At present, it has arrow to change the image on tap.

Comment: Could you please show us first what have you tried to achieve this? Any parts of code?

Comment: Hey Alexzedim, I have no idea of the codes. 
If you want I can share the product page code.